Proving a Gaussian process w/ specified mean and covariance is Brownian motion
I'm struggling with a silly thing when trying to prove that a Gaussian process $(X(t))_{t\geq 0}$ with $\mathbb{E}[X(t)] = 0$ for all $t$ and $\mathbb{Cov}[X(s),X(t)] = \min\{s,t\}$ for all $s,t$ is Brownian motion. Specifically, I struggle to show that under these hypotheses, for each $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n$, the increments $(X(t_{k+1})-X(t_k)), k = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ are independent random variables.

You know that $X(t_0),\ldots,X(t_n)$ are independent? That is not even true.

@geetha290krm Yeah, okay, I'm not sure where I got that from. Edited it out

Compute $Cov (X(t_{k+1})-X(t_k),X(t_{j+1})-X(t_j))$.

Oh, okay. I did not know that fact. Thank you @SassatelliGiulio. Do anyone of you wish to post this as an answer so I can close my question?

Not my solution, credit due to the people who commented on the question.
For multivariate normally distributed random vectors, uncorrelatedness implies independence (see for instance here).
Since the process $X$ is a Gaussian process, it follows for any two non-overlapping increments, $X_{t_{2}} -X_{t_{1}}$ and $X_{t_{4}} - X_{t_{3}}$, the increments are multivariate normal. Then by bilinearity of the covariance and the hypothesis we can write
\begin{align*}cov(X_{t_{2}} -X_{t_{1}}, X_{t_{4}} - X_{t_{3}}) &= cov(X_{t_{2}}, X_{t_{4}}) - cov(X_{t_{2}}, X_{t_{3}}) + cov(X_{t_{1}}, X_{t_{4}}) - cov(X_{t_{1}}, X_{t_{3}})\\\\
&= t_{2}- t_{2} + t_{1} - t_{1} = 0.
\end{align*}
This extends to more than two increments, with analogous computations for each pair of increments.
